# How to get Facebook access token with username / password

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, access-token

Using Facebook graph API I can get the fb access token. And to do so I have to visit the `facebook.com` to allow the application to access my data through the Login dialog.

Is there any way to get the Facebook access token, by using account id and password, from API,  without visiting `facebook.com` / without any application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**User access token**:

If you want to get user access token then the answer is **NO**. You cannot access user access token without making the user visit facebook.

Do some reading on [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) and understand what is its [concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

**App access token**:

If you mean application access token then you can make a curl call to facebook. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/) for details

[Facebook's access token documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) explains the different types of Access tokens and how to obtain and use them - all user access tokens will require direct interaction from a user though

Comment: Then how we can allow the `publish_actions` permissions to the app without visiting facebook?

Answer (score 1):

No, this breaks the convention on [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). The idea is that the user gives you access to **their** Facebook page without releasing **their** username and password to you.

Facebook still controls all the usernames and passwords and the user knows they are only logging into Facebook and you are not siphoning off their username and password for your own means

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, is kind of a blackhat technique tho

https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=&response_type=token

you should make all the ajax calls programmatically, it is a nightmare but i managed to do it for a client so is possible, good luck